# Oracle: Get the row count in a cursor when using a OPEN-FOR-USING statement

Tags: oracle, count, cursors

Within an Oracle procedure, after opening a cursor for a select statement, I fail to find a mean to count the number of rows fetched.

```
OPEN mycursor FOR
SELECT * FROM TABLE;

-- mycursor%ROWCOUNT is always set to 0, even if the cursor has rows.
IF mycursor%ROWCOUNT = 0
THEN
  <error processing code here>
END IF;
```

This is expected, as documented at [Oracles's documentation website](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems034.htm):

> The OPEN-FOR-USING statement associates a cursor variable with a
>   query, executes the query, identifies the result set, positions the
>   cursor before the first row in the result set, **then zeroes the
>   rows-processed count kept by %ROWCOUNT**.

So, except for running a second, redundant 'select count(*) from table', are there any other means to find out the number of rows within the cursor?

**EDIT #1:**  I am not looping after loading the cursor; it is returned as is to the calling procedure.  However, I must raise an exception if there are no row.  These are the specifications.

Comment: You don't need redundant `SELECT COUNT`,  you may just add count  (analytic version) to your main query :  `SELECT .... , COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY NULL) as rec_count .....`

Comment: Just assume the cursor has a rowcount > 0 and start to process it, with an exception handler for 'NO_DATA_FOUND'.  See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-mar/o23plsql-1906474.html

Answer (score 1):

Do the ROWCOUNT check after looping through the set.  If ROWCOUNT will remain 0 if there were no data in the cursor.  You could use a FOR LOOP construct like:

```
OPEN ....

FOR ... IN mycursor
LOOP
    /* Process data here */
END LOOP:

IF mycursor%ROWCOUNT = 0 ...

CLOSE mycursor;
```